# "this" is undefined inside a class method, when it is used as a callback

Tags: javascript, class, this

I know there are *many* questions about `this`, and I have read many answers and references, including [this canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/1925272). However, I am not able to derive a solution to my specific problem.

Here is a sample code:

```js
class A {
  myField;

  constructor(myField) {
    this.myField = myField;
  }

  myMethod() {
    console.log(this.myField);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(myFunc) {
    myFunc();
  }
}

const a = new A("Hello");
const b = new B(a.myMethod);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myField')

It seems that `this` inside `myMethod` is `undefined` and does not refer to the instance of `A`, as I would expect (coming from C#...).

What can I do to refer to `myField`?

Comment: Maybe `bind`: `a.myMethod.bind(a)`?

Comment: Actually, I think the better solution here is to pass the `A` instance to the constructor and let the constructor invoke the instance's `myMethod`.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance  Why? Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: As presented there’s no *reason* to pass just the bound method. The canonical answer provides the two most common solutions (bind, arrow function) but it’s not clear why they’re not working for you.

Comment: Yeah, kinda what Dave said. And I'm wondering if there's a deeper issue that really should be solved by refactoring rather than just giving advice like, "when in doubt, always use `bind`," as this seems to be a fairly general question with a lot of possible solutions. I don't want to steer you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

to refer to your field, you have to use the bind method. bind() is used to borrow methods from another object. In your case the only thing you need to do is bind. Read briefly about it here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_bind.asp

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that **this** is being called in another class (in this case class B) which is not "connected" with class A. You could resolve this by passing the instance "this" in the myMethod function:

```
class A {

  constructor(myField) {
    this.myField = myField;
  }

  myMethod(instance) {
    console.log(instance.myField);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(myFunc, instance) {
    myFunc(instance);
  }
}

const a = new A("Hello");
const b = new B(a.myMethod, a);
```